# How do you convert a string to an integer in Python

Tags: python, string, integer

"""
A trimorphic number is a number whose cube ends in the number itself.

For example:

```
Input: 4
Output: true (4^3 is 64, which ends in 4)

Input: 24
Output: true (24^3 = 13824)

Input: 249
Output: true (249^3 = 15438249)
```

Write a program to check if the user input is a trimorphic number or not.
"""

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
print(num)

num_cube = pow(num, 3)
str(num_cube)
print(num_cube[len(num_cube) - 1:] == num)
```

I tried running the code and I got a TypeError at line 22 (the last line) even though I converted the variable num_cube to a string in order to slice it. Why does it not work?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even see that mistake at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the endswith function to check whether the last "n" characters in the cube are equal to the string representation of the number you are passed.

You could thus do:

```
print(str(num_cube).endswith(num))
```

The way you have currently implemented it, you are "hard coding" the expected length of the number read from the stdin and are thus assuming it to always be of length 1.

To correct your code, you would do the following:

```
>>> num = "24"
>>> num_cube = str(pow(int(num), 3))
>>> num_cube[len(num_cube) - len(num):] == num
True
>>> num_cube[-len(num):] == num # negative indexing
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`str(num_cube)` is not assigned, so you are converting it but still using `num_cube` which is an int, hence the `TypeError`. Also, you need to compare it to another string, not to to `num` which is another integer:

```
print(str(num_cube)[-3:] == str(num))
```